# google maps autocomplete html tables

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the folowing code from google that works ok:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>

<script>

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
      country: 'short_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initialize() {
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
          { types: ['geocode'] });
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        fillInAddress();
      });
    }


    function fillInAddress() {

      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      }


      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
      }
    }


    function geolocate() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
              position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: geolocation,
            radius: position.coords.accuracy
          });
          autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
      }
    }

</script>
```

```
<div id="locationField" style="margin-left: 3px;">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="ADDRESS" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
</div>

<table id="address">

<tr>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>

    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"></input></td>

    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"></input></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I want to add another table with his own input field to auto-complete a second address in a second table but w/o success.

```
<div id="locationField" style="margin-left: 3px;">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="ADDRESS2" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
</div>

<table id="address">

<tr>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country2" disabled="true"></input></td>

    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality2" disabled="true"></input></td>

    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code2" disabled="true"></input></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I see you give some tags the same `id` for example `<table id="address">`
First you should try fix these, you can't use an `id` on several tags.

Comment: Hi, I used another tag on autocomplete2 on inout field and/or table id address2  but no success. I do not know how to make th3 script to work for diferent tags. :(